# Directline - C# API REST - Continue with a bot conversation when the flow leaves the API

Tags: c#, azure, api, rest, direct-line-botframework

We are developing an .Net Core (c#) Rest API who connects a DirectLine Bot with another external application.
The external application sends us by a POST a set of parameters with the information that the bot needs.
The API comunicates with the bot and it returns a first response that returns to the external app.

For this we follow the official documentation, and we obtain the token and the ConversationId like this:

```
var tokenClient = new DirectLineClient(
                        new Uri(Endpoint),
                        new DirectLineClientCredentials(Secret));

                        var conversation = await tokenClient.Tokens.GenerateTokenForNewConversationAsync();
```

Next, we create a new DirectLineClient and we establish the connection with the bot:

```
var client = new DirectLineClient(
                        new Uri(Endpoint),
                        new DirectLineClientCredentials(conversation.Token));
await client.StreamingConversations.ConnectAsync(
                        conversation.Id,
                        ReceiveActivities);
startConversation = await client.StreamingConversations.StartConversationAsync();
```

finally we post the activity like this:

```
var response = await client.StreamingConversations.PostActivityAsync(
            startConversation.ConversationId,
            new Activity()
            {
                Type = "message",
                Text = message,
                From = from
            });
```

and we receive the response with the receiveActivity function.

This is OK.

The problem comes when the external application needs send a response to the same bot conversation. We try creating a new cliente with the same ConversationId and the same Token and establishing the connection, but it doesn't work.

Do we really need to create a new client? or how can we continue with the same conversation
when the flow leaves (and returns) from the API?

Thanks in advance.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Typically, external communications to a running bot are handled via sending [proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp).

Rather than communicating thru your developed API, your external service would post to a secondary endpoint exposed by the bot. Normally, messages are routed thru the `/api/messages` endpoint, but for your proactive message it would go to `/api/notify`. This controller uses a `ConversationReference`, described in the linked doc, to insert the incoming message/activity into the ongoing conversation.

This sample, [16.proactive-messages](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages), demonstrates how you can set this up.

One final note: If you are having the bot call your developed API and are then waiting for a response, be sure to return a response immediately. The DirectLine channel connector will timeout after 15 secs resulting in an error. If you return an activity saying "Getting you your data" or something similar, or even an empty activity, then the connector will be satisfied and you can wait for your external service to return the actual data via the proactive message.